Defining a global <Link> component in svelte in Inertia.js as in vue.js
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import {createInertiaApp, Link} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress'

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: name => {
        const pages = import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue', { eager: true })
        return pages[`./Pages/${name}.vue`]
    },
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .component("Link", Link)
            .mount(el)
    },
});

Can we create this kind of structure in Svelte, like in Vue.js?
I want to use the  component only by defining it in the main js file and calling it wherever I want without calling it over and over again

I have no idea what this is supposed to do. If you describe what this is about without referencing specific libraries, you are more likely to get answers.

No.
